# Align radio button 3 by 3 and export file on same line

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment

I want to align the radio button 3 by 3 and to also align the import file into the same line but further away , like in the wireframe below.
How do i do that?
They are all part of the same form.

```html
 <div class="file-import">
            <label>Choose File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
        </div>
        <div class="excel-selection">
            <p>Choose file type:</p>
             <input type="radio" id="excel1" name="excel" value="option 1">
            <label for="excel1">option1</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="excel2" name="excel" value="option 2">
            <label for="excel2">option2</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="excel3" name="excel" value="option 3">
            <label for="excel3">option3</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="excel4" name="excel" value="option 4">
            <label for="excel4">option4</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="excel5" name="excel" value="option 5">
            <label for="excel5">option5</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="excel6" name="excel" value="option 6">
            <label for="excel6">option6</label><br>
        </div>
```

wireframe of layout [image]

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i don't understand what you want about the file,
for the radio 3 per 3 i made this small code

EDIT:

ok you have two ways to do it depending of what you rather (you have an infinite but there is two)

first one:

HTML

```
<div class="element col1x2">
    <div class="file-import">
        <label>Choose File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="element col1x2">
    <div class="excel-selection">
        <p>Choose file type:</p>
        <div class="element col1x3">
            <input type="radio" id="excel1" name="excel" value="option 1">
            <label for="excel1">option1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="element col1x3">
            <input type="radio" id="excel2" name="excel" value="option 2">
            <label for="excel2">option2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="element col1x3">
            <input type="radio" id="excel3" name="excel" value="option 3">
            <label for="excel3">option3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="element col1x3">
            <input type="radio" id="excel4" name="excel" value="option 4">
            <label for="excel4">option4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="element col1x3">
            <input type="radio" id="excel5" name="excel" value="option 5">
            <label for="excel5">option5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="element col1x3">
            <input type="radio" id="excel6" name="excel" value="option 6">
            <label for="excel6">option6</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.col1x3{
   width: 33%;
}

.col1x2{
    width: 50%;
}

.element{
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The second solution is by using flex:

HTML:

```
    <div class="main">
    <div class="duo">
        <div class="file-import">
            <label>Choose File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="duo">
        <p>Choose file type:</p>
        <div class="excel-selection">
            <div class="element">
                <input type="radio" id="excel1" name="excel" value="option 1">
                <label for="excel1">option1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <input type="radio" id="excel2" name="excel" value="option 2">
                <label for="excel2">option2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <input type="radio" id="excel3" name="excel" value="option 3">
                <label for="excel3">option3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <input type="radio" id="excel4" name="excel" value="option 4">
                <label for="excel4">option4</label>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <input type="radio" id="excel5" name="excel" value="option 5">
                <label for="excel5">option5</label>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <input type="radio" id="excel6" name="excel" value="option 6">
                <label for="excel6">option6</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.duo{
    width: 50%;
}

.excel-selection{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;

}

.element{
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be inline instead that one above the other, like in the wireframe

Comment: i just edited my message with two different solutions :) i recommend you to take flex, with easy code you may center it (exemple: add " align-items: center; " to class main)

BONUS FOR FLEX: 
Oh and the width from the radio, i put it with 33% but if you want to fill with a certain number depending of size of screen for exemple, you can just remove width and check about how to put spacing in flex

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) for this task.

Note that I adjusted your HTML structure, that it works well with the grid. Important is, that each label/input pair is *one* grid item.

```css
.excel-selection {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto auto auto /* rows */
                 / auto auto auto auto;  /* columns */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.fill-height {
  grid-row: span 3;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="excel-selection">
    <p class="fill-height">Choose file type:</p>
     
    <label for="excel1">
      <input type="radio" id="excel1" name="excel" value="option 1">
      option1
    </label>
    <label for="excel2">
      <input type="radio" id="excel2" name="excel" value="option 2">
      option2
    </label>
    <label for="excel3">
      <input type="radio" id="excel3" name="excel" value="option 3">
      option3
    </label>
    <label for="excel4">
      <input type="radio" id="excel4" name="excel" value="option 4">
      option4
    </label>
    <label for="excel5">
      <input type="radio" id="excel5" name="excel" value="option 5">
      option5
    </label>
    <label for="excel6">
      <input type="radio" id="excel6" name="excel" value="option 6">
      option6
    </label>
    
    <div class="file-import fill-height">
        <label>Choose File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
    </div>
</div>
```